# Visual State Manager in WPF not working for me

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, visualstatemanager

In a wpf project I have this XAML code

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WPFToolkit"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Loading">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </vsm:VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
</vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="loadingAnimation">
            <Image x:Name="content" Opacity="1">
                <Image.Source>
                    <DrawingImage>
                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            <DrawingGroup>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1"/>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="angle" Angle="0" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                    </DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0.9,0.5 A0.4,0.4,90,1,1,0.5,0.1">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <Pen Brush="Green" Thickness="0.1"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Green" Geometry="M0.5,0 L0.7,0.1 L0.5,0.2"/>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    </DrawingImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="animation">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="359" Duration="0:0:1.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="angle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="animation"/>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="76.128" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="547.872" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.95*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button" Margin="0,0,1,0.04" Width="100" Content="Load" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Click="Button1_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0.04" Width="100" Content="Stop" Grid.Column="1" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Click="Button2_Click" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Control x:Name="control" Margin="10" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="100" Template="{DynamicResource loadingAnimation}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and the following code behind on the window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Loading", true);
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
        }
    }
```

However, when I click the first button (button1) the state change is not being triggered.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix your code. Your XAML don't match your codebehind. Where is Button_Click handler?

Comment: @majocha: Sorry about that, I copied the XAML prior to doing the change. That wouldn't build, and that's not the deal here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, it is by design on .net 3.5. [This guy](http://jack.ukleja.com/workaround-for-visualstatemanager-gotostate-not-working-on-window/) has a workaround.

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(VS.100).aspx), when you use the Visual State Manager outside of a control template, you should use the `GoToElementState` method, not the `GoToState` method. I have not tested it, though.

Comment: I think you are referring to the v4.0 VisualStateManager. The version on the toolkit for v3.5 does not contain that method.

Comment: You'll need to use the `ExtendedVisualStateManager` for the `GoToState` method

Comment: Did you mean for the `GoToElementState` method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got an error in the designer (VS2008 SP1):

> **Value cannot be null.
>
>    Parameter name: value**

whenever I edit the storyboard code. Reloading the xaml "fixes" the problem temporarily. The code still builds and runs, but I suspect that the cause of this error might have a bearing on your problem.

The definition of the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` looks a little off to me. The only way I've seen it done in the past is as described on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(VS.95).aspx) where it's done like this:

```
<vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
  <Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
          <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</vsm:VisualState>
```

However, I tried that with your code and still couldn't get it to work, so I even if that is 
a problem it's not the whole problem.

Comment: That code was generated by Blend, so I don't know what could be wrong about it. I'm still surprised no one has come yet with a quick solution to a seemingly small problem.

Comment: The problem is the code you posted don't build because there is no handler in codebehind for your first button. Make sure your code builds without errors and runs, then post it again.

Comment: @Román - OK - if Blend generated it, it must be legit. My point about the error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Create one attached property to change the visual state. This will work for you

```
  public class StateManager : DependencyObject
        {
            public static string GetVisualStateProperty(DependencyObject obj)
            {
                return (string)obj.GetValue(VisualStatePropertyProperty);
            }

            public static void SetVisualStateProperty(DependencyObject obj, string value)
            {
                obj.SetValue(VisualStatePropertyProperty, value);
            }
                public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStatePropertyProperty =
              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
              "VisualStateProperty",
              typeof(string),
              typeof(StateManager),
              new PropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
              {
                  var propertyName = (string)e.NewValue;
                  var ctrl = s as Grid;  
                  if (ctrl == null)
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("This attached property only supports types derived from FrameworkElement.");
                  var transitionWorked = System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(ctrl, (string)e.NewValue, true);
                               }));
        }
```